# adding Search Widget through code in orchad

Tags: orchardcms, qwidget

i am checking the possibility of adding a search widget through code or placement info . just tried   . but not working

Any info is appreciated

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Where do you want to place it? Why not through the widgets in the dashboard? What have you tried?